# Euler 22 code not returning correct answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have been trying to do Problem 22 on Project Euler, but I cannot seem to get the right answer or see any problem with my code. I copied and pasted the contents of the txt file rather than accessing it directly from my code.

https://projecteuler.net/problem=22

```
namelst = open(names.txt)
namedict = {} 
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
for x in namelst: 
  score = 0   #creates score for each word
  for y in x: 
    score += alphabet.index(y.lower())+1   #adds alphabetic score for each letter 
  namedict[x] = score

namedict = sorted(namedict.values())   #creates list of scores ordered by size 
scoresum = 0
for x in namedict:
  index = namedict.index(x)+1
  scoresum += x*index   #multiplies score sum by order in the list

print(scoresum)
```

Unfortunately, this leaves me with an answer of `985466567`, while `871198282` is the correct answer. Is there any error in my code or method?

If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. There are a few problems with your code:

1. `namedict` is not a dictionary, it is a list.
2. The requirement is to sort alphabetically by name, not by value.
3. You need to use or store indices of your sorted list. I use `enumerate` for this.

Combining these elements:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

namelst = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
namedict = {} 
alphabet = ascii_lowercase

for x in namelst: 
    score = 0
    for y in x: 
        score += alphabet.index(y.lower())+1
    namedict[x] = score

namelist = sorted(namedict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

print(namelist)
# [('abc', 6), ('def', 15), ('ghi', 24)]

scoresum = 0
for idx, x in enumerate(namelist, 1):
    scoresum += idx*x[1]

print(scoresum)
# 108, i.e. 6 + 30 + 72
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is very helpful!